# "Simple" Released login

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to figure out a rolebased login system, the redirects users to two different HTML pages using JavaScript. Im using localstorage to store the password, username and AuthenticationLevel ( This is supposed to be differentation between users level 1 users and level 2 users).

1. Made a class UserLogin and stored in a LocalStorage
2. tried to make a simple login system that pulls usernames, passwords and authlevel out of my localstorage to redirect users to two different sites.

But I get

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'UserLogin' has already been declared User.js:25

```js
//Users
class UserLogin {
  constructor(username, password, authLevel) {
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.authlevel = authLevel;
  }
}
// Localstorage logins
if (localStorage.getItem("userLogin") == null) {
  var userLogins = [];
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Benjamin", 4321, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Mads", 12345, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Simon", 1234, "1"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Jessica", 54321, "1"));
  // Logins for Projectmanagers
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Oliver", 1234, "2"));
  userLogins.push(new UserLogin("Sara", 4321, "2"));

  var userLoginstring = JSON.stringify(userLogins)
  localStorage.setItem("userLogin", userLoginstring)
} else {

}
var UserLogin = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserLogin"))


this.usernameInput = document.getElementById("username");
this.passwordInput = document.getElementById("password");

let aLevel = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("authLevel"));

let existingUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("UserLogin"));

function checkLogin() {

  for (let i = 0; i < existingUser.length; i++) {
    if (usernameInput.value == existingUser[i].employee_user && passwordInput.value == existingUser[i].password) {
      currentLogin.push({
        username: usernameInput
      })
      var IDString = JSON.stringify(currentLogin);
      localStorage.setItem("UserLogin", IDString);
      alert("Login successfully");
      console.log('virker');
      if (aLevel[i].level == 2) {
        document.location = "employeeList.html";

      } else {
        document.location = "Medarbejderside.html";
      }
      return true;
    } else {
      console.log('Doesn'
        t work ');
        attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have wrong attempt;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt === 0) {
          document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
          document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
          return false;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: You use same name for class and var. Rename your class

Comment: It is pretty pointless to have a login system if the credentials are stored in plaintext in the script

Comment: I know, its just for a school project, we do not have any acces to databases :)